# Multi-scoring input RandomizedSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, scoring

I know you can input multiple scorers when performing `RandomizedSearchCV` but I couldn't find which one will then be used for optimisation.

```
scoring = {'Log loss': 'neg_log_loss', 'AUC': 'roc_auc', 'F1': 'f1', 'Bal Acc': 'balanced_accuracy'}

search_RF = RandomizedSearchCV(RF_model, parameters_RF, scoring = scoring, 
                                n_jobs = -1, cv = cv_RSKFCV, n_iter = 200,
                                random_state = 2504).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

In the above example, will it then optimise the `'neg_log_loss'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It optimises all of them, taking into consideration one at a time.
You can check the results for all of them in `search_RF.cv_results_`.

Also you should use `refit` parameter, instead of keeping it to default as you will get an error if you will try running `search_RF.best_estimator_`.

Follow below links for more details:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_multi_metric_evaluation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-multi-metric-evaluation-py

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html#multimetric-grid-search

Comment: Hi Chandan!

Thank you for your comment. Is there a way that I could optimise just neg_log_loss but only print the other scorings? I thought that refit is by default true?

Comment: use Refit = 'neg_log_loss' and then search_RF.best_estimator_ would print just neg_log_loss and you can get other parameters from search_RF.cv_results_

Comment: That's a very good suggestion. Thank you!